# Angular - I am trying to populate and select from dropdown menu from array object values

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, arrayobject, arrayofarrays

I am getting some issues in dropdown and array objects.

I am trying to select value from dropdown menu but right now the array values is not populating inside the dropdown menu.

i am not getting what is the error.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    
constructor(private title: Title) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.title.setTitle('Select through Dropdown');
    }
    
    selectedCity: String = "--Choose City--";
  
    City: Array<any> = [
        // City=[
        { 
            name: 'India',
            states: 
            [ 
                { 
                    name: 'Karnataka', 
                    
                    cities: ['Bangalore', 'Gulbarga', 'Thumkur', 'Coorg' ]

                } , 
                { 
                    name: 'Andhrapradesh',
                    cities: [ 'hyderabadh', 'x', 'Y', 'Z' ] 
                }
            ] 
        },
        
        {   
            name: 'USA',
            states:
            [
                { 
                    stname: 'California',
                    cities: [ 'Los Angeles', 'San Francisco' ]
                }, 
                
                { 
                    stname: 'Texas', 
                    cities: [ 'Houston', 'Dallas' ] 
                } 
            ] 
        },
    ];
    

    selected = "----"

    changecities(city: any){
        this.selected = city.target.value

        console.log (this.selectedCity );
    }
    
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="content" style="background-color: rgb(196, 195, 195);">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Select Your Choices</h2>

    <div class="card-container" style="padding-bottom: 2em; padding-left: 10em;">
        <label>City : </label>
            <select placeholder="City" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" (change)="changecities($event)">
            <option>--Choose City--</option>
            <option *ngFor="let city of City" >
                {{city.cities}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <p>You selected {{selected}}</p>    
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I am not able to access the values of cities in dropdown menu.

how to solve this issue guys, Thank you

Comment: which cities do you want to access? there are multiple countries with cities in your data

Comment: @AT82 i want to access all the cities in a single dropdown

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all cities from all countries in a single dropdown, I would want to flatten the array you have to an array of strings, and instead show that in the template, so what you can do is to declare a new variable, for example `cities` and then map and flatten the data:

```
this.cities = this.City.map(x => x.states.map(y => y.cities)).flat(2)
```

and then in template:

```
<option *ngFor="let city of cities">
  {{ city }}
</option>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-frezf9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**